# c++ reading file two columns

Tags: c++, file

I am given a txt file that has more than two columns of numbers. I have to read first two columns and first 100 lines into arrays and later do some calculations. I have managed to read them correctly `cout << temp1 << ' ' << temp2 <<'\n';` when I print this I get numbers as they are in file, but when I print actual arrays I get some different numbers.. I do not know how to fix this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void func(){
    int col1[100];
    int col2[100];
    int temp = 1;
    ifstream in;
    in.open("file.txt");
    if (in.fail()){
        cout << "failed to open" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    string line;
    int temp1, temp2;

    while(getline(in, line) && temp <= 100) {
        int j = 0;
        istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> temp1 >> temp2;
        cout << temp1 << ' ' << temp2 <<'\n';
        col1[j] = temp1;
        col2[j] = temp2;
        j++;
        temp++;
    }
    cout<<"arrays"<<'\n';
    for (int i=0; i < 100; i++){
        cout << col1[i] << ' ' << col2[i] <<'\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: You put the declaration of `int j` inside the loop, meaning you always `col1[j] = temp1` always writes to the same first element of `col1`. Move the declaration of `j` outside the loop. Or better yet, use `std::vector` and lat the language manage array sizes for you.

Comment: Is it better to use vectors rather than arrays?

Answer (score 2):

Your `j` is initialized to 0 on each loop iteration. Effectively, you only initialize `col1[0]` and `col2[0]`, with the rest elements of the arrays being uninitialized garbage.

Comment: yes it works now..

Answer (score 1):

You redefine j for each loop iteration (j will always be `0`)

```
while(getline(in, line) && temp <= 100) {
        int j = 0;
        // ...
        col1[j] = temp1;
        col2[j] = temp2;
        j++;
        // ...
}
```

try to move `int j = 0` before the loop

```
int j = 0;
while(getline(in, line) && temp <= 100) {
        // ...
}
```

Comment: it works.. silly mistake thank you